# WPF modified project

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a wpf with loads of textboxes and comboboxes etc... And I have a button which allows them to be saved as an xml file. It's not binded or anything, I just serialize it. Now I want to be able to set a boolean if any of the textboxes or comboboxes are modified, so for example, if i close the application it can check the boolean and ask if it needs to be saved or not. I can imagine it's possible by setting this boolean on all events, but there's so many of them, it's crazy to do this.

Is there a better option? Maybe through binding? (not really a pro on binding)

Answer (score 0):

```
bool TrueExit
private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
if (TrueExit)
            {
                MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Save?",
                    "The End", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Stop);
                if (result == MessageBoxResult.No)
                    e.Cancel = true;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Binding is definitely the preferred choice with WPF. If you use INotifyPropertyChanged, you could create an additional boolean for each property representing each UI elements content.

So, if I had a TextBox bound to property "MyProperty", I would also create a boolean called "IsMyPropertyChanged", and do this:

```
public bool IsMyPropertyChanged { get; set; }

private string _myProperty;
public string MyProperty
{
    get
    {
        return _myProperty;
    }

    set
    {
        if (value != _myProperty)
        {
            // Update property
            _myProperty = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("MyProperty");

            // Set flag
            IsMyPropertyChanged = true;
        }
    }
}
```